# Grouping Result Min/Max in a breaking series ascending/descending order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select Min and Max in a ascending/descending order series if series breaks the data order

suppose I have data in a order by DateTime :

```
LogDate      StartValue EndValue    Multiplier  DiffValue
2016-02-08   7661.25    7677.62     6.94        16.37
2016-02-09   7677.62    7693.02     6.94        15.4
2016-02-10   7693.02    7709.82     6.94        16.8
2016-02-11   7709.82    7727.08     6.94        17.26
2016-02-12   7727.08    7740.93     6.94        13.85
2016-02-13   3.02       12.22       6.94        9.2
2016-02-14   12.22      20.73       6.94        8.51
2016-02-15   20.73      37.04       6.94        16.31
2016-02-16   37.04      52.56       7           15.52
2016-02-17   52.56      67.82       7           15.26
2016-02-18   67.82      83.66       7           15.84
2016-02-19   83.66      98.77       7           15.11
2016-02-20   98.77      108.37      7           9.61
```

And I want the result Like :

```
LogDateMin  LogDateMax  StartValue  EndValue    Multiplier  SumOfDiffValue
2016-02-08  2016-02-12  7661.25     7740.93     6.94        79.68
2016-02-13  2016-02-15  3.02        37.04       6.94        34.02
2016-02-16  2016-02-20  37.04       108.37      7           71.34
```

here I am grouping the result by Multiplier also and getting sum of deffValue

How can we achieve this

Please help

Comment: what do you mean by  if series break  data order in above example

Comment: See the example of stopwatch its data flows in ascending order but if user reset the watch then it will restart the CurrValue from zero or a min value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, "break" means a minimum value threshold between the values as time flows.

In order to obtain the results, I have used `LEAD` and `LAG` functions to find the breaks, as they provide value before and after current record without using `self` `JOIN`.

Then, I have created the groups that contain only the first and last record near the "break". The `resultset` contains dates and values as rows, so an `UNPIVOT` is required.

The final query should look like this:

```
declare @Threshold NUMERIC(18, 2) = 1000

;with DeltaCte as (
    SELECT DateTime, CurrValue, 
        LAG(CurrValue, 1, CurrValue - @Threshold - 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) AS PrevVal, 
        LEAD(CurrValue, 1, CurrValue - @Threshold - 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) AS NextVal
    FROM RawData
)
,GroupsCTE AS (
    select DateTime, CurrValue, CurrValue - PrevVal AS Delta1, CurrValue - NextVal AS Delta2, 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) + 1) / 2 AS GroupNo
    FROM DeltaCte
    WHERE ABS(CurrValue - PrevVal) > @Threshold OR ABS(CurrValue - NextVal) > @Threshold
)
SELECT GroupNo, MIN(d) AS DateTimeMin, MAX(d) DateTimeMax, 
    MIN(v) AS CurrValueMin, MAX(v) CurrValueMax
from GroupsCTE
UNPIVOT (v FOR nValue IN ([CurrValue])) AS P1
UNPIVOT (d FOR nDate IN ([DateTime])) AS P2
GROUP BY GroupNo
```

**[EDIT]**

If "break" means break of ascending order, above query becomes slightly simpler:

```
;with DeltaCte as (
    SELECT DateTime, CurrValue, 
        LAG(CurrValue, 1, CurrValue + 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) AS PrevVal, 
        LEAD(CurrValue, 1, CurrValue - 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) AS NextVal
    FROM RawData
)
,GroupsCTE AS (
    select DateTime, CurrValue, CurrValue - PrevVal AS Delta1, CurrValue - NextVal AS Delta2, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) + 1) / 2 AS GroupNo
    FROM DeltaCte
    WHERE (CurrValue - PrevVal < 0) OR (NextVal - CurrValue <  0)
)
SELECT GroupNo, MIN(d) AS DateTimeMin, MAX(d) DateTimeMax, 
    MIN(v) AS CurrValueMin, MAX(v) CurrValueMax
from GroupsCTE
UNPIVOT (v FOR nValue IN ([CurrValue])) AS P1
UNPIVOT (d FOR nDate IN ([DateTime])) AS P2
GROUP BY GroupNo
```

Basically, delta to threshold comparison is replaced with delta to 0 comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot @alexei